# "Can be originated" vs "can originate"

Tags: word-choice, tense, verbs, modal-verbs, aspect

While writing the thesis, google docs proposed me to use **"can originate"** instead of **"can be originated"**. Seriously, is there any difference? I am not a native speaker, that's why I am asking. The full quote is below.

> New genes **can be originated** from existing ones when previously
> independent genes are joined together and expressed as a single unit.

Comment: google doc proposed I use. Not proposed me to use.

Comment: Google docs is a machine, not a native speaker. Machines are not noted for discriminating taste. This question involves a subtle point of usage between a verb with a transitive and an intransitive meaning. Please read Colin Fine’s excellent answer.

Answer (score 2):

*Originate* can be used transitively or intransitively.

When it is transitive, it has a causative sense: it means "bring into being, cause to be".

When it is intransitive, it does not have that causitive sense: it means "come to be".

So if you use the passive "be originated" that is a form of the transitive, causitive verb, and so implies that somebody or something originated the thing.

Of course, you are talking about a process that did bring the new genes into being, and so the passive *be originated* is possible.

At first I thought the intransitive *originate* was  more natural, like the other repliers. But on reflection, I think your *be originated* is better here, because you are talking about the process.

Comment: Why can’t I upvote more than once!

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Colin Fine’s answer 100%.

The other two responders find the sentence awkward due to the passive verb. There is merit in what they say, but, as Colin Fine has explained, their solution changes your intended meaning.

There are some foolish people who say that you should never use the passive voice. That is nonsense; use the passive voice whenever it is necessary. Stylistically, however, the active voice has the advantage of making clear from the beginning who or what is acting.

> Joining together previously independent genes originates new genes.

That is a more concise way to get your thought across. But we are now talking about style rather than grammar, and style is subjective.

Answer (score -1):

In this case the suggestion from Google docs is a good one. "Can be originated" is grammatically correct (or almost so, and understandable) but awkard and ugly.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I am impressed you are writing a thesis in a second language.  Google docs suggested that you use "can originate" because the "be" sounds awkward to native speakers. It is not necessary. Honestly I can't give you the exact grammatical reason, but it doesn't sound right. Good luck on the rest of your paper!

Comment: I do not intend to be harsh, but I suggest that you not answer if you cannot articulate a reason for your answer.